# Unicode letters replaced by ***** (letter n )

Tags: unicode, console

the letter n is being replaced with **** in my console when I run dbt.

[image: the letter n is being replaced with **** in my console when I run dbt.]

In text format:

```
11:59:24 Fou*****d 397 models, 15 tests, 0 s*****apshots, 0 a*****alyses, 639 macros, 0 operatio*****s, 11 seed files, 335 sources, 0 exposures, 0 metrics
11:59:24 
11:59:53 Co*****curre*****cy: 1 threads (target='dev') 
11:59:53 
11:59:53 1 of 1 START table model ................. [RUN] 
11:59:57 1 of 1 OK created table model ............ [SUCCESS 1 i***** 3.27s] 
11:59:57 
11:59:57 Fi*****ished ru**********i*****g 1 table model i***** 32.94s
```